# Compatibility Issues with Lenovo and ThinkPad Docking Station

Tags: laptop, power-supply, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, docking-station

I recently purchased a new computer along with a docking station. According to Lenovo, the two should be compatible. After all, their website states that this docking station should work for the computer, which is why I went ahead and bought it.

Now, the issue I'm facing is that my computer goes into standby mode intermittently, displaying a message on the screen that goes something like: "You are not using the originally supplied charger; the current one has insufficient wattage." However, I have a 135-watt power supply connected to the docking station, and my computer only requires 100 watts. It's hard to imagine that the docking station would require more than 35 watts.

I also rule out a driver issue; I have already downloaded and updated all drivers from the official website. In theory, everything should be functioning correctly.

Laptop: [Link to Laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/at/de/p/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-500-series/ideapad-pro-5-gen-8-(16-inch-amd)/83ar0028ge#compatible_acc)

Docking Station: [Link to Docking Station](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/docking/docking_usb-docks-(universal-cable-docks)/40af0135us?orgRef=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

Comment: Since you purchased this new, you should contact Lenovo Support first and ask about the adapter issue.